# SQL- Can you Delete a row in BigQuery and Move the deleted row to another table?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, sql-delete

I have looked at the documentation on the available statements but I have not seen any statement that will enable me to move deleted rows to another table.

here is a snippet of sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE %s;
 INSERT INTO rm.table_access (%s) VALUES (%s);
 DELETE FROM rm.table_access
    Where (%s) LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' AND  -7 AND -077 AND -77 
    OUTPUT Deleted.(%s) INTO test_tables;
```

Any ideas how to approach this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in BigQuery. It has no implementation of the kind of virtual tables for modified and deleted rows that some traditional RDBMS have.

To implement something similar, you would need to select the rows to be deleted into a new table FIRST (using a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement), then delete them from the main table.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would suggest you create a new table with appropriate filters for each. You can use the ***CREATE TABLE dataset.newtable AS SELECT x FROM T***, you can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#column_name_and_column_schema). Thus, your syntax would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `your_new_table` AS SELECT * 
FROM `source_table`
WHERE  VALUES LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' AND VALUES LIKE '-7' AND VALUES LIKE '-77'
```

I used single quotes in the *WHERE* statement because I assumed that the field you are filtering is a *String*. Another option would be using the function ***REGEXP_CONTAINS()***, you can find out more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains). Your syntax for the filter would be simplified, as follows:

```
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(VALUES,"HEARTBEAT|STRING|STRING")
```

Notice that the values you compare using the above method must be a String. Therefore you have to make sure of this conversion before using it, you case use the [CAST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#castingfunctions) function.

In addition, if you want to delete rows in your source table, you can use [DELETE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_examples). The syntax is as below:

```
DELETE `source_table` WHERE field_1 = 'HEARTBEAT'
```

Notice that you wold be deleting rows directly from your source table.

I hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Creating a new table with the rows you desire and another table with the "deleted" rows.

```
#Table with the rows which match the filter and will be "deleted"
#Notice that you have to provide the path to you table 
#`project.dataset.your_new_table`
CREATE TABLE `your_new_table` AS 
SELECT field1, field2 #select the columns you want
FROM `source_table`
WHERE  field1 LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' AND field1 LIKE '-7' AND field1 LIKE '-77'
```

Now, you get the rows which did not passed through the filter in the first step.They will compose the table with the desired rows, as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_desired_rows` AS 
SELECT field1, field2 #select the columns you want
FROM `source_table`
WHERE  field1 NOT LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' 
   AND field1 NOT LIKE '-7' 
   AND field1 NOT LIKE '-77'
```

Now you have your source table with raw data, another table with the desired rows and a table with the rows you ignored.

**Second option:**

If you do not need the raw data, that means you can modify the source table. You can first create a table with the ignored rows and then delete these rows from your source data.

```
#creating the table with the rows which will be deleted
#notice that you create a new table with these rows
CREATE TABLE `table_ignored_rows` AS 
SELECT field1, field2 #select the columns you want
FROM `source_table`
WHERE  field1 LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' 
   AND field1 LIKE '-7' 
   AND field1 LIKE '-77';
#now deleting the rows from the source table
DELETE `source_table` WHERE  field1 LIKE 'HEARTBEAT' 
   AND field1 LIKE '-7' 
   AND field1 LIKE '-77';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have more questions 1) I would need to select the rows to be deleted into a new table how would that be possible?

Comment: You can select the columns and filter your dataset in order to export the rows you want to delete to a new table, you can also do that to create a new table to the rows you want to keep. However, if you export the ones you want to delete and then delete these from your table source. All of these can be done with the methods I showed above. In case, you don't know how to do it I can update the answer showing you step by step.

Comment: sure that would be helpful